# Many microphones in windows

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, c#, pcm

I need to record from as many as 40 microphones simultaneously on a single Windows 7 PC.  These microphones will be present as USB audio adapters connected to powered USB hubs (so limited power isn't an issue.)  I'd like to capture audio in PCM, 44.1khz, stereo, 16 bit.

Is this possible?  Can Windows detect 40 microphones, and will I be able to access them simultaneously?  Is there a maximum number of USB devices Windows can detect?

Comment: Are they audio jack microphones, or USB, or network, or what?  USB has a 127 device limit.  It will be hard to find a sound card or even multiple sound cards to get 40 jacks so straight up audio jacks are probably out.

Comment: @cybernard USB audio adapters connected to independently powered USB hubs. Thanks, I'll add that to the question.

Comment: What is your sampling rate? 8khz....96khz or what?

Comment: @cybernard 44.1khz, stereo, 16 bit, though that might be flexible.  Could drop to maybe 32khz, stereo, 16 bit if necessary.

Comment: Using a few hubs ( a couple may need to be USB 3.0) physically connecting them should be a non-issue.  It **should** work.  The software your using could be a limiting factor. 40 * 400kb/s(max) is only 16mb/s so hard drive speed should not be an issue you can upgrade to a SSD if it is.  However, I have never actually done this so there could be issues.

Comment: Ah, ok.  My hunch was it was possible, just wanted to see if I was off base here. Thanks @cybernard you were incredibly helpful. If you'll post an answer I'll accept it.